# "Python" clean data frame from unwanted ip addresses

Tags: python

I have a data frame that has a column called IP addresses and i want to drop all rows that do not have that stem `137.182.0.`

Actual data frame

```
    IP addresses    column 
    137.182.0.77    value1 
    137.182.0.33    value2
    32.142.8.29     value3
    137.182.0.43    value4
    137.182.0.11    value5
    37.112.2.2      value6
```

Expected output

```
    IP addresses    column 
    137.182.0.77    value1 
    137.182.0.33    value2
    137.182.0.43    value4
    137.182.0.11    value5
```

Comment: What code have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is one of the answers that might work for you:

```
df[df['IP addresses'].str.startswith('137.182.0.')]
```

Here `df['IP addresses'].str.startswith('137.182.0.')` returns a Series of booleans indicating whether the given pattern ('137.182.0.') matches the start of each string element (your IP address). Please take a look at the documentation: [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) Hope it helps!

Comment: Very nice! Thank you.